# Multithreading in PHP with the use of Javascript ajax, possible?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm developing a game based on Html5, JavaScript (jQuery) and ajax with the use of PHP as Server Side. Now what is in the game is, there is a different types of jobs that you can assign to you players as per Job time duration. Suppose I have assign one job`JOB1` to one player`PLAYER1` with the duration of 10 minutes and other job `JOB2` to other player `PLAYER2` with the duration of 30 minuted. Means,

```
PLAYER1 = JOB1(10MINS)
PLAYER2 = JOB2(30MINS)
```

Now I want to create multithreading in PHP to handle this two jobs parallel and get the request to client side after every minute complete of that job.

I know that there are various ways to create multithreading in PHP and I can send the request to PHP server to create the thread when job is started with the use of ajax, but how can I get the data back to the client side and display the data after every minute?

It is possible or not? What are other options to do the same thing?

Comment: Create a queue with jobs, worker(s) and queue for results.

Comment: nice question. i also want to know this

Comment: You should just save which job belongs to which player and use something like long polling to get the information if the job is finished. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more of a task for multiprocessing rather than multithreading.

To create another PHP thread you would use something like `pcntl_fork`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

But in a request/response type situation, such as HTTP, you would more likely start a seperate process and then poll it from the client.

To do such a thing with PHP you would create another process on the CLI using the `&` operator (linux only, if you need windows let me know and Ill update the answer), and he poll it using either:

- A file, which the process outputs status information to it,
- A database, likewise as above,
- Or a shared memory segment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a php-library called "spork" https://github.com/kriswallsmith/spork that is a wrapper arround the pcntl_fork functions.

it works pretty well and stable for me.